# Let $a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_{100}$ be non-zero real numbers such that$a_1+ a_2+\cdots+ a_{100}=0$. Then $\sum_{i=1}^{100} a_i 2^{a_i}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, inequality, exponential-function, tangent-line-method

Let $a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_{100}$ be non-zero real numbers such that $$a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_{100} = 0$$ Then

A - $\sum_{i=1}^{100}  a_i 2^{a_i}\ge0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{100}  a_i 2^{-a_i}\ge0$

B-   $\sum_{i=1}^{100}  a_i 2^{a_i}\gt0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{100}  a_i 2^{-a_i}\lt0$

C    $\sum_{i=1}^{100}  a_i 2^{a_i}\le0$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{100}  a_i 2^{-a_i} \le 0$

D    The sign depend upon the choice of $a_i$

I tried adding $\sum_{i=1}^{100}  a_i 2^{a_i}$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{100}  a_i 2^{-a_i}$ but I am stuck. No idea what to do next.

P.S:
The option B was earlier typed incorrectly. Corrected the typing mistake.

Comment: There is no nice formula that you can simplify that sum to and just read off whether the answer is negative. You need to try some examples. What about $50$ of the $a_i$ being $1$ and the rest being $-1$? Try a few different simple things like that, and see what happens. It should at least let you rule out one or two alternatives. If D is the true answer, this testing might give you some intuition about what sequences might demonstrate that, and if not, the testing might give you the intuition you need to show that as well.

Comment: You shouldn't edit the question to change its meaning 45 min after posting it and having answers!  Either get it right the first time, or post another Q.

Comment: Sorry, I will be more careful next time. I promise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the following reasoning solves all problems.
$$\sum_{i=1}^{100}a_i2^{a_i}=\sum_{i=1}^{100}\left(a_i2^{a_i}-a_i\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{100}a_i\left(2^{a_i}-1\right)\geq0$$
because for all real $x$ we have $x(2^x-1)\geq0.$

The equality occurs for $a_1=a_2=...=a_{100}=0$, which says that the equality does not occur.

Id est, $$\sum_{i=1}^{100}a_i2^{a_i}>0.$$

By the same way we can get that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{100}a_i2^{-a_i}<0.$$

Comment: @Macavity See please better my solution. In the first line the inequality is $\geq$.

Comment: Ah, I missed seeing you saying equality does **NOT** occur. +1  This is indeed the right solution for the revised problem.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**  Well, if $a_i$ satisfy the condition, then so does $-a_i$.  Then note that multiplying by $-1$ should reverse the inequality, whichever it is!

--

P.S. *adding more detail*

If possible, say $\sum a_i 2^{a_i} \geqslant 0$ for all $a_i$ satisfying the condition.  Then $\{-a_i\}$ also satisfy the same condition, so we must have $\sum -a_i2^{-a_i} \geqslant 0$.  Multiplying by $-1$, we get $\sum a_i 2^{-a_i} \leqslant 0$.  The same argument holds if either $A, B, C$ are taken as hypothesis, so none of them can be true.

Comment: It's not _that_ simple, because you have the sign of the exponent to take into account as well.

Comment: @Arthur Yes, that's precisely why it works.  Try it out.

Comment: It doesn't reverse the inequality, because the powers of two that were dominant become negligible, and the ones that were negligible become dominant when you swap signs on the $a_i$.

Comment: It will invariably reverse. Try it out.

Comment: do you mean that if one is positive then the other should be negative?

Comment: @SivaSankarSajeev I have added more detail, do let me know in case you have any further clarifications needed.

Comment: Now it is clear why the sign reverses ,thank you;

Comment: It will not invariably reverse. Take the example in my comment to the original post above: fifty of the $a_i$ are $1$, fifty are $-1$. Then swapping all the $a_i$ with $-a_i$ won't change a thing, the sum remains the same.

Comment: Yes ,you are correct. So they either reverses the sign or both will equal to zero

Comment: If I understand your argument it eliminates options A and C. But option B is presented with signs that are already in the opposite direction. Did you catch that? (Or has the question maybe been edited?)

Comment: @alex.jordan That's an edit the OP made a couple of minutes ago, which clearly changes the question.  In any case that's trivially eliminated, by reversing the $a_i$ with $-a_i$ to start with.

Comment: yes ,I had edited question. Typing mistake.

Comment: You still haven't decided between B (the new one) or D. But with the clarification at least my concerns have been addressed.